# How to repaint QQuickItem quickly?

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2, frame-rate

I have a stream of images, in YUY2 format. I would like to paint these images on `QQuickItem` - so I can use it with Qt Quick 2.

I have an issue with the performance so my question is what is the quickest way to redraw QML object written in C++? Is there some kind object dedicated to rendering videos?

---

What I have tried is creating a class that inherits `QQuickPaintedItem`. I have converted YUY2 images to RGBA8888 format, then loaded it using `QImage` and then painted it using `QPainter`. It proved not efficient if `QQuickPaintedItem` was big - for example bigger than 1000x1000. Much quicker method was to convert `QImage` to `QPixmap` and then paint using `QPainter`. It works somewhat good now but maybe there is quicker way? For example conversion of images seems too slow the process down.

Comment: You won't get any better performance if you use `QQuickPaintedItem`. You could implement an item with custom geometry and a simple shader to fill a quad with the texture you desire. Then feed the item new textures. The display and scaling will be very quick. There might already be examples of that. You can also use `QQuickFramebufferObject` and update the texture from the render subobject.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks for the help. If you wish, post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got this to work by using [`QQuickItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html) with defined [`updatePaintNode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#updatePaintNode) function (the first idea from [Kuba Ober's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329652) comment).

[This example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-graph-example.html) helped me a lot. In it `NoisyNode` class renders background (static image) and `Graph` is using it. I have taken those two class to my project and adapted them to my needs. I had no problem displaying 1080x1920 pixels, 30fps. As I understand to display a video you eventually need to convert YUV to RGB so I did this right away and worked with an array of RGBA pixels.

Comment: In case the link to the example dies - it is Scene Graph example from Qt docs. The example should be shipped with Qt IDE. If not, there should be some other example showing how to create an object with customized updatePaintNode function.